# Removing taken numbers from a List

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<double>` with several numbers. What I'm trying to do is look at what `doubles` are similar to each other; add up all similar numbers and get the average. So for example a list: `{ 2.1, 2.2, 4, 4.1, 8, 8.2}` would become: `{2.15, 4.05, 8.1}`

What I'm having some issues with is when I look for similar numbers using this LINQ statement: `tempList = points.Where(p => Abs(p - currentPoint) < 0.25).ToList();`, how do I also simultaneously remove all the points from the `points` list that I picked into `tempList`, so that I'm not looking at the same numbers over and over again (e.g. referring back to my example; if I just looked at `2.1`, I don't want to look at `2.2` on the next iteration because I just found the average is `2.05` for all numbers similar to `2.1`.etc).

Here were my attempts:

```
points = points.Except(tempList).ToList();
//and
foreach (var t in tempList)
{
    points.Remove(t);
}
```

I successfully remove the point from the `points` list, BUT, in my main look where I'm going through each of the points, it still iterates over DELETED points, which I find very strange.

Comment: Are you looking for answer using Linq, or is a loop fine?

Comment: @ispiro Either one. Also, I've already tried using `Except()`, in my loop that I'm using to go through the `points` list, but I still end up iterating over the number that I removed using `Except()`.

Comment: Is it based on left-to-right precedence? For `{1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6}`, does the `{1.1,1.2,1.3}` get smooshed together then `{1.4,1.5,1.6}`. Because it could also be `{1.1,1.2}` then `{1.3,1.4,1.5}` then `{1.6}` or many other combinations.

Comment: @Chee'sBurgers There is no "smooshing" involved. Once the average of all similar numbers are found to the current number I'm looking at, that is it—I move on to a completely different number that is completely out of range of the previous number. What I need to do is get rid of all numbers that were involved in the calculation of the average (aka the `tempList` numbers subtracted from the `points` list).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question describes a specialized logic that seems somewhat like a moving average but is only using the existing values to calculate the average. This requires a look-ahead approach as you cannot know whether the "current" value will be used in the final sequence without using the next value in the sequence. While this type of logic could be done using Linq extension methods like Skip and Take, I don't see a reasonable way to use the Linq syntax for this. This makes for a good academic exercise. But, in the real world, this use case demands a straightforward approach. Even if you could get it to work, the Linq syntax would be far less readable and maintainable, and would almost certainly take a performance hit relative to the more direct approaches.

However, one of the most useful features of Linq is the library of extension methods. These provide a "fluent interface" that allows for a flow of several operations in a single statement. The following example uses the same approach and returns the results expected by the OP (as mentioned in the question and some comments). It is flexible, expressive, and should perform well. And it is as close to Linq as you are going to get for this type of application.

```
static public class MyExtensions
{
    static public IEnumerable<double> GetPointAverages(this IEnumerable<double> points)
    {
        var e = points.GetEnumerator();
        var reading = e.MoveNext();
        while (reading)
        {
            var value = e.Current;
            reading = e.MoveNext();
            if (reading && e.Current - value < .5)
            {
                value = (value + e.Current) / 2;
                reading = e.MoveNext();
            }
            yield return value;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var pointsArray = new[] { 2.1, 2.2, 2.6, 4, 4.2, 4.7, 4.8 };
        var averages = String.Join(", ", 
            pointsArray.GetPointAverages().Select(p => p.ToString())
            );
        Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", averages);
        Console.WriteLine();
        var pointsList = new List<double>() { 8.8, 9.0 };
        averages = String.Join(", ", 
            pointsList.GetPointAverages().Select(p => p.ToString())
            );
        Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", averages);
   }
}
```

--

```
Result: 2.15, 2.6, 4.1, 4.75

Result: 8.9
```

The use of both an array and a List is intended to demonstrate that it doesn't matter what kind of collection you use to hold the values as long it supports `IEnumerable<double>`.

--

It could be useful to see the various constructs that were investigated before arriving at the answer above. The OP mentioned using a "while" loop. This led to some experimentation to reproduce the desired results with the goal of converting the tested approach to Linq syntax.

Here's a Linq example using one statement and that assumes "similar" means having the same integer value:

```
var points =
    from p in new[] { 2.1, 2.2, 4, 4.1, 8, 8.2 }
    group p by (int) p into avgs
    select avgs.Average();

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", points.Select(p => p.ToString())));

Result: 2.15, 4.05, 8.1
```

The OP asked about averaging within .5 of the "current" number. Setting aside the definition of "current" for the moment, here's an example of averaging only numbers that are within .5 of their integer value.

```
var points =
    from p in new[] { 2.1, 2.2, 2.6, 4, 4.2, 4.7, 4.8 }
    let intp = (double)((int)p)
    let grp = (p - intp < .5) ? intp : p
    group p by grp into avgs
    select avgs.Average();

var averages = String.Join(", ", points.Select(p => p.ToString()));

Console.WriteLine(averages);

Result: 2.15, 2.6, 4.1, 4.7, 4.8
```

The concept of "current" number eliminates Linq syntax as an option. When using Linq as it is designed to work, you are only ever looking at one item in a sequence. You, theoretically, have no knowledge of position within a sequence or of the other items in the sequence. The grouping mechanism allows you to use aggregation methods that accumulate values in an "as you go" fashion. Using a "current" number as posed in the question requires a look-ahead approach and an ascending ordered sequence. Knowledge and use of these are not part of the Linq design. However, translating what we have done in Linq into looping logic may help lead to a solution that is Linq-like.

The above Linq statement would translate into a loop something like this:

```
var points = new[] { 2.1, 2.2, 2.6, 4, 4.2, 4.7, 4.8 };
var groups = new Dictionary<double, List<double>>();

foreach (var p in points)
{
    var intp = (double)((int)p);
    if (p - intp < .5)
    {
        if (!groups.ContainsKey(intp))
        {
            groups[intp] = new List<double>();
        }
        groups[intp].Add(p);
    }
    else
    {
        groups[p] = new List<double> { p };
    }
}

points = groups.Select(dict => dict.Value.Average()).ToArray();
```

The "for" loop translation would look something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
{
    var p = points[i];
    var intp = (double)((int)points[i]);
    if (p - intp < .5)
    {
        if (!groups.ContainsKey(intp))
        {
            groups[intp] = new List<double>();
        }
        groups[intp].Add(p);
    }
    else
    {
        groups[p] = new List<double> { p };
    }
}
```

As a rule of thumb, if you can imagine iterating using a foreach, you can almost certainly use Linq. If you need access to other items in the sequence while iterating, the Linq syntax is not going to work.

The following "for" loop will return the expected results and gives us an idea of how we could use the enumerator to solve our problem. The extension method shown at the top of the answer was derived from this logic. It is more flexible and should perform just as well.

```
var tmpPoints = new List<double>();
for (var i = 0; i < points.Length;)
{
    var value = points[i];
    var next = i + 1;
    if (next < points.Length && points[next] - points[i] < .5)
    {
        value = (points[i] + points[next]) / 2;
        i = next + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
    }
    tmpPoints.Add(value);
}

points = tmpPoints.ToArray();

// Results using the two example sequences

points = new[] { 2.1, 2.2, 2.6, 4, 4.2, 4.7, 4.8 };

Result: 2.15, 2.6, 4.1, 4.75

points = new[] { 8.8, 9.0 };

Result: 8.9
```

Comment: What if I wanted to calculate the average for numbers within `0.5` of the current number. So for example, say I have: `{ 2.1, 2.2, 2.6, 4, 4.2, 4.7, 4.8}`. So in that case, when I'm looking at `2.1` only `2.2` is within the range, and when I look at `2.6` there is nothing within range, so its just `2.6`...so essentially, the averages would come out to be: `{2.15, 2.6, 4.1, 4.75}`. I  have have a `while` loop that can do this, however, I'd like to know if there is a way to do this an easier way using LINQ.

Comment: I updated the example. I am still trying to get a handle on how the notion of "current" could work in Linq. It's an interesting use case.

Answer (score 2):

This is the other form of rhaben's answer:

```
var list = new List<double> { 2.1, 2.2, 4, 4.1, 8, 8.2 };

var newList = list.GroupBy(d => (int)d).Select(g => g.Average()).ToList();
```

Comment: What if I wanted to calculate the average for numbers within 0.5 of the current number. So for example, say I have: { 2.1, 2.2, 2.6, 4, 4.2, 4.7, 4.8}. So in that case, when I'm looking at 2.1 only 2.2 is within the range, and when I look at 2.6 there is nothing within range, so its just 2.6...so essentially, the averages would come out to be: {2.15, 2.6, 4.1, 4.75}. I have have a while loop that can do this, however, I'd like to know if there is a way to do this an easier way using LINQ.

Comment: something like `.GroupBy(d => (int)(d*2))`

Comment: It kind of works. The issue with that is when I have numbers like `{8.8, 9.0}` and nothing else, I want the average of those two numbers since `9.0` is within range of `8.8`, but because of the grouping, this doesn't happen :/

Comment: You can easily adjust that by subtracting a small number from the grouping (int)(0.5/d-0.05)

Answer (score 0):

So you want the average of the sum of `x` and all numbers that is between `x` and `x + 1`? Then here's he solution:

```
List<double> numbers = new List<double>() { 2.1, 2.2, 4, 4.1, 8, 8.2 };
List<double> averages = new List<double>();

// This compares the first number in the sequence to all others. When all "matches" have been found, the matches and the first number is deleted. Repeat until no numbers are left
while (numbers.Count > 0) 
{
    int numberOfMatches = 1; // The number at numbers[0] is a match
    double sum = numbers[0]; // Add numbers[0] to the sum

    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.Count; i++) // Go through all number except the first
    {
        if (numbers[0] <= numbers[i] && numbers[i] < (int)numbers[0] + 1) // If numbers[i] is withing the x to x + 1 range
        {
            sum += numbers[i]; // Add the new number
            numberOfMatches++; // Increase the number of numbers summerised

            numbers.RemoveAt(i); // Remove the current number since it's already been used
            i--; // Go back one step to not skip a number, since a number was just removed
        }
    }

    numbers.RemoveAt(0); // Remove numbers[0]

    averages.Add(sum / numberOfMatches); // Add the average to averages
}
```

The result in averages?

> > {2.1500000000000004, 4.05, 8.1}

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    var list = new List<double> { 2.1, 2.2, 4, 4.1, 8, 8.2};
    var avereges = new List<double>();


    list.Sort();


    double sum = list[0], original = list[0], count = 1;


    for (int i = 1; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        var isSimiliar = Math.Abs(original-list[i]) < 0.25;

        if (isSimiliar)
        {
            sum += list[i];
            count++;
        }

        if (!isSimiliar || i == list.Count-1)
        {
            avereges.Add(sum/count);
            count = 1;
            sum = list[i];
            original = list[i];
        }
    }


    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", avereges));
```